# Why is a reference type an lvalue when accessed with a temporary object?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does assigning a value to a reference variable being accessed using a temporary object work, but not for a non-reference type?

```
class a
{
    public:
        int m;
        int &n;
        a():m(2),n(m)
        {
            cout<< "A's constructor"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    // a().m = 6; // this gives an error that a temporary object is being used 
                  // as an lvalue
    a().n = 20;   // But this line works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact wording* of the error message?

Comment: **Exact error message**
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp: error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 3):

But is `a().n` truely a temporary? Consider this code:

```
class a
{
    public:
        int m;
        int &n;
        a():m(2),n(m)
        {
            cout<< "A's constructor"<<endl;
        }

        a(int& _n):m(2),n(_n)
        {
            cout<< "A's constructor"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    a().n = 20;   // (1)

    int n = 0;
    a(n).n        // (2)

    return 0;
}
```

The line `(2)` clearly shows that `.n` is not a temporary. It must not be, since it's a reference to the local `n` variable.

But then, the compiler cannot know what `n` will refer. One could even do `n(rand_bool() ? m : _n)` and it must work.

The compile instead uses the type system to know what should be assigned or not.

For example, the literal `9` is a pr-value of type `int`. You can't assign to it:

```
9 = 8; // nope
```

In your code, `a()` is a prvalue or type `a`. All of its value member also are. This is why `a().m` won't work. `m` is a prvalue.

But, `a().n` is an lvalue because `n` is a lvalue reference. No matter to which variable it points to.

Answer (score 1):

```
a().n = 20;
```

works since `n` is a lvalue reference type. The compiler does not know that `n` is a reference to `m` in the implementation. It assumes that `n` is a valid lvalue reference and hence accepts that line.

In theory, when you assign to `a().n`, you could be assigning to a variable that lives independent of the life of `a()`. The compiler has no way of assessing that and will be in the way of the programmer if it didn't accept that line. Imagine the use case below:

```
// Global variable.
int gv;

class a
{
    public:
        int m;
        int &n;
        a():m(2), n(gv)  // n is a reference to the global variable.
        {
            cout<< "A's constructor"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    a().n = 20;   // Changes gv. It is a valid operation.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose my understanding more than a real answer.

I can present the question in another light with this snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
struct S {
    int val;
    int& rval = val;
    int* pval = &val;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "(S{}.val)\tint&&\t" << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<decltype((S{}.val)), int&&>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "(S{}.rval)\tint&\t" << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<decltype((S{}.rval)), int&>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "(S{}.pval)\tint*&&\t" << std::boolalpha
              << std::is_same<decltype((S{}.pval)), int*&&>::value << '\n';
}
```

Which outputs

```
(S{}.val)   int&&   true
(S{}.rval)  int&    true
(S{}.pval)  int*&&  true
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/qb1EcvTK7)

My understanding from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category:
`S{}.xxx` are glvalue because they are named. Period.

> a glvalue (“generalized” lvalue) is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object or function;

As `S{}.val` and `S{}.pval` are accessed through the materialization of a temporary, their ressources can be reused after the expression usage, making them expiring values: xvalues.

`S{}.rval`, on the otherhand, is an unmutable "ressource", as a reference can not be changed (only the ressource it references), thus it would disqualify the expression as xvalue, it can then only be a lvalue.
Or maybe we can say that a reference is not a ressource at all. I'm afraid to be unable to give a clearer explanation for this case.
A hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70039351/is-a-named-rvalue-reference-ref-a-xvalue): `S{}.rval` is not movable.

NB this explanation is failing if I [add constness](https://godbolt.org/z/5G4GrvG1j): according to my dubious "unmutable/non-movable" argument, I would have expected that all the expressions would become xvalues. It's visibly not the case.